# How to upload file in database?

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to upload an image file with the code below, but the file is not being uploaded. The console still shows the message "1 Record Successfully Inserted."

```
Create table image
(
   name varchar2(20),
   photo blob
);

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ImageWriter {

    static Connection connection = null;
    static CallableStatement pstat = null;
    static String connectionURL = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "SYSTEM", "SYSTEM");

            PreparedStatement pstat = connection.prepareStatement("insert into image(name,photo) values(?,?)");

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("E:\\test.jpg");
            pstat.setString(1, "ABC");
            pstat.setBinaryStream(2, fin,fin.available());

            int result = pstat.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(result + " Record Successfully Inserted");

            connection.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why do you want to save an image into DB? You can just save the image path and leave the image file in server...

Comment: You have done insertion then whats wrong.?

Comment: insertion is done only for name field not for photo field.As I am seeing data in database for photo, it shows data not available.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you just do `pstat.setBinaryStream(2, fin);`, i.e. without the `fin.available()`?

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine. 
I dont know how you verified the contents of database.

Here is my code to verify the db(blob column): Try with this method. I used your code to insert the image and I could retrieve the image successfully.  (note : file extension should be same)

```
public static void getPic() {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "sys as sysdba",
                "Oracle123");

        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        oracle.sql.BLOB photo = null;
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String name="ABC";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from  image where name = '" + name + "'" );
        rs.next();
        photo = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB(1);
        File f = new File("E:/image2.jpg");
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
        f.createNewFile();
        InputStream in = photo.getBinaryStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int length = (int) photo.length();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        out.writeTo(outputStream);
        System.out.println("Image Retrieved");
        out.close();
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```